# How to get all physical interfaces

Tags: c++, linux, interface, netlink

I want to get all the physical interfaces on a system, I saw a lot of references to [getifaddrss](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) but it gets all interfaces, disregarding whether it's vlan / macvlan or physical interface.
I can only assume `netlink` will be able to do so (when a socket is created out of a network namespace).

Answer (score 0):

Use **sysfs** -- simply walk over `/sys/class/net`. It will also show relationship between devices such as bonding, bridges. However VLAN may only be guessed from device name (there are patches that bind `8021q` to sysfs, but they were not accepted to kernel).

Here is my code that does this: https://github.com/myaut/tsload/blob/master/agent/lib/libhostinfo/plat/linux/netinfo.c